# How to create a dotnet standard class library with platform-dependent dependencies?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I want to create a .Net Standard class library, with some sort of native dependency that there's .so/.dll pre-built on all platforms I wanna support; for my own purpose, it's OpenCL which I'd like to build a library upon.

I've noticed in [dotnet/corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), there's several components which have platform-specific dependencies. How this works? How can I create a project like this?

Edit: To specify my question, let's say I want to create a Visual Studio .Net Standard Class Library project, in which I'll be able to use different opencl dynamic library on different platform (P/Invoke OpenCL APIs is exactly what I need). How to do this? (Not using OpenCL.Net since it hasn't been updated since 2013.)

Comment: I find it hard to understand your question. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @JSantos Concrete case provided. Sorry for bothering ;)

Comment: Since you already know Microsoft has the code at GitHub, why not check one of the projects? You can also create an issue there to ask the experts. No point to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've figured it out by myself...

For a general project which may depend on platform specific codes and dependencies, the solution is to provide different configurations for different platforms, if following what corefx does.

For this case, I want to P/Invoke OpenCL interfaces, the best way is simply use `DllImport` combined with conditional compiling (`#if`), and thus refer to different dynamic libraries in different configurations (Win32, Win64, Linux, OSX and so on).